# Why derived class pointer which points to base class can call derived class member function?

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
    void doBase() {
        cout << "bar" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    void doBar() {
        cout << "bar" << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Base* b_ptr = &b;
    Derived* d_ptr = static_cast<Derived*>(b_ptr);
    d_ptr->doBar(); //Why there is no compile error or runtime error?
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is `bar\n`.

`d_ptr` is in fact pointing to a Base class while it 's calling a derived class member function.

Is it a undefined behaviour or something else?

Comment: "_Why there is no compile error or runtime error?_" Why should there be? It's, simply, undefined behavior.

Comment: Re: "Why there is no compile error or runtime error?" -- just bad luck. The behavior of the program is undefined, and sometimes the result is that the program does just what you expect. Until it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is undefined behavior.

There is no compile-time error because you used `static_cast` - this is a way to tell the compiler "I know the type better than you do". You are telling your object is `Derived`. You lied to the compiler - thus the undefined behavior.

It happened to work because `doBar()` does not use any `Derived` members.

Comment: Ok. But then I add a `int a = 3;` in Derived class and `cout << a << endl;`  it in `doBar()`. No error again. It just gives me garbage value.

Comment: So "garbage value" is not an error for you? You would like the program to terminate with an error message? That would be defined behavior. Undefined Behavior means the program can do anything.

Comment: @Rick -- "undefined behavior" means only that the language definition does not tell you what the program does. It does not mean that bad things **will** happen, just that bad things **can** happen.

Comment: @PeteBecker Okay :P